# Can I define a function where the body is a quoted body in clojure?

Tags: clojure

So, this is what I want to do

```
(def body `(prn sth))
(defn f [sth] body)

(f "hello")
; can it prn hello here?
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, and what do you want to accomplish eventually?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "take a data structure and embed it in code to be executed", then you can do something like this.

You will want to tweak the body to embed like this:

```
(def body `(prn ~'sth))
```

that is, prefixing the `sth` local variable with `~'` so that it will not be namespaced. Then you need a macro that will embed the code for you:

```
(defmacro insert-body [body]
  (eval body))
```

Using this macro inside the `f` function to embed the body and putting things together, you get this code:

```
(defmacro insert-body [body]
  (eval body))

(def body `(prn ~'sth))
(defn f [sth] (insert-body body))
```

You can now call `f` with an argument and it will work as expected:

```
> (f "hello")
"hello"
nil
```

The function `macroexpand` comes in handy to test that the macro does what it is supposed to be doing:

```
(macroexpand `(insert-body body))
;; => (clojure.core/prn sth)
```

But it is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish or what you would gain from writing your code this way. Whatever you want to accomplish eventually, there is most likely a better way to accomplish it than what I suggest here. I am just providing a specific answer to your question, nothing more, nothing less. So if you clarify your question and give more details, it will also be possible to provide a better answer that addresses you actual problem.

Comment: Why did you need to wrap the eval in a macro?

Comment: This should be enough: ``(defmacro body [] `(prn ~'sth))``
`(defn f [sth] (body))`

Comment: @BipedPhill That is a good point: `eval` will fail to evaluate the local variable `sth`. Elaborated here: https://nakkaya.com/2010/09/02/eval-with-local-bindings/

Comment: @Rulle your `~'` to avoid namespacing is really the trick here! Thanks!